# Remove all subscribers at once

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap-api, soap

Is there a way to remove all subscribers in a list without making a seperate request to delete each subscriber?

Comment: Depends - what is a "subscriber"?

Comment: @JohnWestenhaver did you notice the marketing-cloud/exacttarget tag ?

Comment: Missed that entirely - sorry!

Comment: Are you removing them from the list or the entire application (All Subscribers list)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just delete the [List object](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/list/), which will in essence delete the subscriber's list membership?

Here's a sample SOAP envelope.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Delete</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:cec6826f-1ac3-4559-934b-a5ad8e081c3c</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://webservice.s4.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
      <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
         <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
            <u:Created>2015-01-30T15:29:13.355Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2015-01-30T15:34:13.355Z</u:Expires>
         </u:Timestamp>
         <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-3bd5c867-ef2e-4768-a5e7-3a119b1a8765-11">
            <o:Username><!-- Removed--></o:Username>
            <o:Password><!-- Removed--></o:Password>
         </o:UsernameToken>
      </o:Security>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <DeleteRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options>
            <SaveOptions />
         </Options>
         <Objects xsi:type="List">
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
            <CustomerKey>aspriggs-test-list</CustomerKey>
         </Objects>
      </DeleteRequest>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```